# JPA error: The state field path '***' cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: jpa, spring-data, jpql

```
After running the following query method....   


@Query(value = "select s.owner, " +
            "count(case when s.status = 3 then 1 else null end) as agreed," +
            "count(case when s.status = 2 then 1 else null end) as rejected," +
            "count(case when s.status = 1 then 1 else null end) as pending " +
            "from Schedule s where (s.owner = ?1) " +
            "group by s.owner")
```

here status is fetched from a enum and i have a converter class for that.But during runtime it gives the below exception that while calling convertToDatabaseColumn on converter class com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus$TypeConverter with value 1.e

Any help regarding the issue will be very helpful.Seek experts attention.

This is the error log :

```
ReportQuery(referenceClass=Schedule jpql="select s.owner, count(case when s.status = 1 then 1 else null end) as agreed,count(case when s.status = 2 then 1 else null end) as rejected,count(case when s.status = 3 then 1 else null end) as pending from Schedule s where (s.owner = ?1) group by s.owner")
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.prepareFailed(QueryException.java:1596)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:911)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:615)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1614)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: An exception occurred while calling convertToDatabaseColumn on converter class com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus$TypeConverter with value 1
```

Comment: And your question is? Where is the relation between the title and the content of your "question"? What action triggered the exception? What did you try to fix it?

Comment: No QueryDSL in the question, so title fixed

Comment: @JensSchauder please have a look now.hope you will get it now.

Comment: Please add your converter class and enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do either

Change s.status = 3 (this should be enum) 
Example s.status = Status.ACTIVE

or

Change s.status(should be integer) = 3 
Example: s.status.id = 3

Comment: @Query(value = "select s.owner, " +
            "count(case when s.status = com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus.AGREED then 1 else null end) as agreed," +
            "count(case when s.status = com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus.REJECTED then 1 else null end) as rejected," +
            "count(case when s.status = com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus.PENDING then 1 else null end) as pending " +
            "from Schedule s where (s.owner = ?1) " +
            "group by s.owner")           this solved it.By using the fully qualified package name.

Answer (score 0):

by using the fully qualified package name this can be solved.

```
@Query(value = "select s.owner, " + "count(case when s.status = com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus.AGREED then 1 else null end) as agreed," + "count(case when s.status = com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus.REJECTED then 1 else null end) as rejected," + "count(case when s.status = com.orsbv.hcs.model.schedule.ScheduleStatus.PENDING then 1 else null end) as pending " + "from Schedule s where (s.owner = ?1) " + "group by s.owner")
```